# piecewise warp function of skimage is giving black border line in the output image

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import PiecewiseAffineTransform, warp
from skimage import io


calc_height = 100
calc_width = 100


tform = PiecewiseAffineTransform()
l1 = np.float32([[0,0],[100,0],[100,100],[0,100]])
l2 = np.float32([[0,0],[100,0],[100,100],[0,100]])
tform.estimate(l1,l2)

input_image = io.imread('input.jpg')
output_image = input_image
output_image = warp(input_image, tform, output_shape=(calc_height, calc_width))
io.imsave('output.jpg',output_image)
```

input.jpg is a green 100 X 100 image. When I give a identity transformation, the output.jpg should be same as input.png, but there seems to be a black border line appearing. Can anyone help me how to fix it ? Thanks!

input

[image: input]

output

[image: output]

Comment: Your comment below about the borders probably explains what is going on, but this doesn't look quite right to me; please file a bug on GitHub so we can take a closer look.

Comment: Even I thought so, if it is considering the outside pixels as zero/black pixels for calculations, the black border should have been symmetric, but it is visible only on the left side. I'll file a bug on github @StefanvanderWalt

Answer (score 1):

warp function works with border pixels as well, the default mode is to take them as constant zero/black pixels. Instead use reflect to ensure continuity.

output_image = warp(input_image, tform, output_shape=(calc_height, calc_width),mode='reflect')